# What is the data type for barcodes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, model-view-controller

I have an Excel CSV file with a `Barcode` column that has data that looks like this: `5.06E+12` - it has a decimal number(5.06), letter(E) and symbol(+).

When I try to edit this in Excel, the number changes to `5060190000000`.

When storing this type of data to my SQL Server database, what should the data type be of my Model's `Barcode` property?

Comment: You should store this as a string . . . say, `varchar(10)`.  Normally, though, a value represented that way is storing a floating point number, which is why you see the full value in Excel.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-numbers-in-scientific-exponential-notation-f85a96c0-18a1-4249-81c3-e934cd2aae25

Comment: So varchar(50) would be acceptable since the example of 5060190000000 is of length more than 10?

Comment: Thanks for that link Robin. I just want to store the barcode so that in the future, users of my application can shop faster by using a barcode.

Comment: @aladdin786 - `VARCHAR` would be an appropriate data type. The length  of the field would depend on the amount of data actually encoded in the bar code.

Comment: Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to pick the most appropriate data type. If you're using actual product barcodes, a little research indicates that they're likely [International Article Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Article_Number).

Since they're really strings of 13 digits, a `char(13)` would probably be the most appropriate data type to store this data. Don't just default to `varchar(50)` because that's "big enough" - think of the length specification as free validation.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [E notation](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Scientific_notation#/E_notation) which is a variation of scientific notation. The number in question is an integer, but is abbreviated.

```
5.06 * 10^12 = 5060190000000
```

<strike>Thus, your value should be stored as an integer large enough to store your number.</strike>

Your value should be stored as a varchar long enough to fit the length of potential values.

Comment: Depending on the range, potentially a [bigint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187745.aspx).

Comment: The maximum number of digits for an `int` is 10 and even then that range is limited.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect that you need an integer large enough to store your number, such as a bigint if the number is sufficiently large.

Comment: Also, if it's a barcode, it's likely that this should be dealt with as a *string* of digits. You're not going to add barcodes together or do other maths with them, and leading zeroes may be possible.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are right. Edited my answer.